# What events do a hand-held remote clicker fire in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I want to capture the events from a remote clicker (Logitech R400) in the browser. However, I am not sure how to capture them. Does anyone know how to capture them?

If I add an event listener to the body, no events fire with the clicker.

```
$('body').on('keypress', function(e){
    //none of the buttons on a clicker fire this event
    console.log(e.keyCode);
});
```

How do I get an event to fire with a clicker. Anyone ever use a clicker and know how to do this?

Comment: If you're going to do a canonical, please include all details like you would if you didn't have the answer. As is, this question itself is too broad and technically should be closed.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I hope that helps explain what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I was using the `keypress` event to detect the inputs form the remote clicker. But I noticed that not all keys fire an event with `keypress`. This made me sad.

So I decided to try `keydown` instead. MAGICALLY, all other keys do fire this event. I was able to find out that the `keydown` event will fire with a clicker. For the logitech, and I imagine any clicker, the following keyCodes relate the clicker buttons:

```
element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    switch(event.keyCode){

        case 33: //left or previous

        case 34: //right or next

        case 27: //start or play

        case 116: //stop or exit

    }
});
```

Both the `27` and `116` event.keyCodes get fired with the play button. I am guessing that one is to play and the other is to exit. Not sure why the same button switches back and forth between the 27 and 116 keyCodes.

Comment: Just for completeness, it's worth mentioning that key codes 33 and 34 are "Page Up" and "Page Down", respectively. To make it work with the arrow keys as well, you would need to add 37 (left) and 39 (right).

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working on a Logitech R400. There are four buttons the top right and left arrow buttons are page up and down.The bottom right button is registering the . key on keydown.

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton'); 
// Handle Bottom Right Button on Logitech R400 (Period Key)
if(event.key === "Period" || event.keyCode === 190) {
    console.log(`Right button (Page Down) pressed Key: ${event.key}, 
KeyCode: ${event.keyCode}`);
    myButton.click(alert('Period Key Pressed'));
}
// Handle PageDown key Top Right Button on Logitech R400
else if  (event.key === "PageDown" || event.keyCode === 34) {
console.log(`Right button (Page Down) pressed Key: ${event.key}, KeyCode: 
 ${event.keyCode}`);
 myButton.click(alert('Page Down Key Pressed'));
}
});
</script>
```